# how to load images from sdcard in corona sdk

Tags: android, coronasdk

How can I display a image from sdcard or phone memory using corona sdk?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Corona SDK to develop for iOS but I believe corona apps are sandboxed and you are not able to read anything outside the sandbox. Thought this might only be true for iOS apps.

Comment: i think u r right .. i googled about this issue but didn't get any proper answer and i feel stack overflow has less corona developer! i got only16view in 5 days... its hard to get answer here.. thnks for your comment.. i mean answer..

Comment: no worries. I'm afraid Ansca, to make Corona work on both Android and iOS platforms had to drop support for reading files from outside the sandbox. I don't think Corona is as popular as Cocos2d to get such attention in here. You are better off asking questions on their forums.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to read and write files on the SD-card using LFS and IO APIs on Android.

To access the phones inbuild memory, add the android permission "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" and set the path to "/". From there you can access the memorycard.

Example:

```
local lfs = require("lfs")
local path = "/"
local pathType = ""

-- Check to see if path exists
if path and lfs.attributes( path ) then
    pathType = lfs.attributes( path ).mode
end

-- Check if path is a directory
if pathType == "directory" then
   for file in lfs.dir( path ) do
       if "." ~= file and ".." ~= file then
          -- Get the file attributes.
          local fileAtr = lfs.attributes( path .. "/" .. file )
          -- Print path, name and type of file (Directory or file)
          print(path,file,fileAtr.mode)
       end
    end
end
```

This will print the path, filename and type of file in the terminal window. (Have only tested on Mac and Android device.)

I have found a way to display an image outside the sandbox on Android and on the simulator. (PC not tested)

Example:

```
local lfs = require("lfs")
    --------------------------- Change this path ---------------------------
local path = "path/to/the/image.jpg"                                    -- Change this path to the path of an image on your computer
------------------------------------------------------------------------


local tmpPath = system.pathForFile("tmp.jpg",system.TemporaryDirectory) -- Destination path to the temporary image

--------------------------- Read ----------------------------
local file, reason = io.open( path, "r" )                               -- Open the image in read mode
local contents
if file then
    contents = file:read( "*a" )                                        -- Read contents
    io.close( file )                                                    -- Close the file (Important!)
else
    print("Invalid path")
    return
end

--------------------------- Write ----------------------------

local file = io.open( tmpPath, "w" )                                    -- Open the destination path in write mode
if file then
    file:write(contents)                                                -- Writes the contents to a file
    io.close(file)                                                      -- Close the file (Important!)
else
    print("Error")
    return
end

---------------------- Open and remove -----------------------
local img = display.newImage("tmp.jpg",system.TemporaryDirectory)       -- Display the image from the temporary directory
os.remove(tmpPath)                                                      -- Removes the image, so that we can load another image.
```